# Trying to recreate a shake animation like Stripe

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to recreate a negative shake animation, like the Strike uses in their payment box, when there are some form fill errors.

I basically copied it animation keyframe, but in my usage it doesn't work of the same way.

My Version:

http://codepen.io/FelipeMartinin/pen/NGrXvR

Stripe Version:

https://stripe.com/docs/checkout (Click in "Pay with Card" Button and after click in "Pay" without fill the inputs to see the animation)

If you note, the Stripe animation there is a 3d movement effect, and in my version, the box shakes only horizontally. Even with the same keyframe.

Follow in below the keyframe

```
@keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.headShake {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: panelShakeAnimation;
  -moz-animation-duration: 400ms;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-name: panelShakeAnimation
}
```

How to make my animation works like Stripe? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add a `perspective` rule on your container element. This makes it so the transformation will appear in 3D space.

**Live Demo:**

```js
$("button").on('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
  
 $(".card").toggleClass("headShake");
});
```

```css
/* Basic Reset */
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 1.875;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #555;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/* Basics Styles */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2196f3;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4.8rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.lead {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.main-title {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-subtitle {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
}

.text-small {
  font-size: 75%;
}

.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.display__inline {
  display: inline;
}

/* Padding Helpers */
.padding-tb {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

/* Basic Demo Styles */
.site-container {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 60.063em) {
  .site-container {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}

.footer__content {
  margin-top: 1.6rem;
}

/* Card */
.card {
  top: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1em;
}
.card h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Material Design Form Inputs */
.form__wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.form__wrapper--submit {
  padding: 1.6rem 0;
}

.form__input {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.84em 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #444;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #2196f3 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #2196f3 4%);
  background-position: -400px 0;
  background-size: 400px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /**
   * Remove default box-shadow for required pseudo classes 
   */
  /**
   *  When input contain a class of .error 
   */
}
.form__input:required {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.form__input.error {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #f44336 4%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #f44336 4%);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 400px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.form__input:focus {
  background-position: 0 0;
  color: #444;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -moz-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
}

/* Form Label */
.form__label {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1em);
  text-align: left;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #999;
}

/* Form Label Content */
.form__label-content {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -moz-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
}

/**
 * 1. When input is focused move the label to top
 * 2. when the input field has a value move the label to top
 */
.form__input:focus ~ .form__label .form__label-content,
.form--filled .form__label-content {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -65%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -65%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -65%, 0);
}

/**
 * Error Styles
 * .error class generated by jquery.validate.min.js plugin
 */
.error {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #f44336;
  display: block;
}

/* Basic Buttons */
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.btn:focus, .btn:hover {
  background-color: #0d8aee;
}
.btn.btn-block {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Modal Styles */
.modal {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  z-index: 999;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -moz-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -ms-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -o-transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
}

/* Close icon style for model */
.modal--close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  color: #888;
}

.modal--open {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}


@-moz-keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

@-o-keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}
  
@keyframes panelShakeAnimation {
  0 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }

  12.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg);
    transform: translateX(-6px) rotateY(-5deg)
  }

  37.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg);
    transform: translateX(5px) rotateY(4deg)
  }

  62.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg);
    transform: translateX(-3px) rotateY(-2deg)
  }

  87.5% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg);
    transform: translateX(2px) rotateY(1deg)
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
}

.headShake {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 400ms;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-name: panelShakeAnimation;
  -moz-animation-duration: 400ms;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-name: panelShakeAnimation;
}

.site-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="main-title">Head Shake Animation</h1>
<h2 class="main-subtitle">An amazing animation for negative feedbacks</h2>

 <section class="site-container padding-tb">
  
  <section class="card" style="opacity: 1; transition: none; transform: translateY(0px) scale(1); margin-top: -244px;">
   
   <h3 >Login Form</h3>

   <form action="#" class="form" method="post">
       <div class="form__wrapper">
           <input type="email" class="form__input" id="email" name="email">
           <label class="form__label" for="email">
      <span class="form__label-content">Email</span>
     </label>
        </div>

       <div class="form__wrapper">
           <input type="password" class="form__input" id="password"  name="password">
           <label class="form__label" for="password">
      <span class="form__label-content">Password</span>
     </label>
          
        </div>

       <div class="form__wrapper--submit">
        <div class="form__input-submit">
            <button  class="btn btn-block">Submit to run</button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
    

  </section><!-- /card -->


   </section><!-- /site-container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Add perspective to the container, to get the 3-d effect

```
.site-container {
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding-left: 0.6em;
  padding-right: 0.6em;
  perspective: 400px;
}
```